# specifying conditions as a variable to subset a data frame in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame, `df` with 30 columns: `A1` to `A30`. I know that I can subset this data frame by writing a command like:

```
 filteredrows = subset(df, A1 == 30 & A2 == 2 & A3 == "this")
```

The above example filters data based on values in three columns, but I have to do this for values in about say 12 columns. Writing those 12 values in the subset() function will make it too long. To make the code cleaner, is there a way I can specify the condition as a variable or a function and then use that specify the conditions in the subset function. Is something like the following possible?

```
x = (A1 == 30 & A2 == 2 & A3 == "this")
filteredrows = subset(df, x)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the condition as an `expression` and then pass it to subset using `eval`:

```
d <- data.frame(x=letters[1:10],y=runif(10))
ss <- expression(x == "a")
subset(d, eval(ss))
```

Comment: I can't decide whether this technique is beautiful or awful.

Comment: @hadley - :shrug: Was just the first thing that popped into my head that does what the OP asked. But you're the expert, not me. I love learning: why's it awful? I'd gladly upvote an answer with a better method that explains why this one is bad.

Comment: It is beautiful because it works and I can see any simpler way. It's awful because there are two sets of quoting and evaluating - yours and the ones inside subset.

Comment: @hadley - if you think this is not in general a good practice, please let me know the "correct" way to do this. Can the restrictions be specified in a list?

Comment: The "correct" way, if it's even reasonable to be so bold, is probably to do as you originally suggest.  It's not clear to me why you think it's too long and why anything else would be cleaner.  When I do something like this, it's usually because I'm going to be doing the subset several times for some reason, in which case putting the set into the data frame as I suggest might be a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Your suggestion almost works, you just need a `with` when you get `x`.

```
> df <- expand.grid(A1=(1:3)*10,A2=1:3,A3=c("this","that"))
> x <- with(df, (A1 == 30 & A2 == 2 & A3 == "this"))
> subset(df, x)
  A1 A2   A3
6 30  2 this
```

You could also get the subset this way.

```
> df[x,]
  A1 A2   A3
6 30  2 this
```

You may also want to put `x` in the data frame `df`; otherwise reordering the data frame can mess things up, something like

```
df$x <- with(df, (A1 == 30 & A2 == 2 & A3 == "this"))
subset(df,x)
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron. This, however, did not work for me since I wanted to specify the conditions, independent of the data frame's name.

Comment: Oh, my first downvote!  (Not that I /really/ care, of course...)