# Using subset function with variable columns?

Tags: r

I'm using the subset function in R and I'm wondering if there's a way for me to define the column name as a variable, and then subset that column name?

For example, right now I have something like this:

```
data.subset <- subset(df, age >= n1 & age < n2)
```

But say I wanted to subset on height instead of age. I want to have a variable that I can just set to `"height"` and the subset will subset on height instead.  I'm doing this to have a function that is adaptable. Something like this:

```
my.column <- "height"
data.subset <- subset(df, my.column >= n1 & my.column < n2)
```

Comment: Note the warning section on the help page `?subset`.  Following Ben Bolker's suggestion of directly subsetting is a much better idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *insist* on using `subset` you can mess around with `eval(parse(text=paste(...)))` (ugh!) but given what you're trying to do, `subset` will be more trouble than it's worth.

```
my.column <- "height"
data.subset <- df[df[[my.column]] >= n1 & df[[my.column]] < n2),]
```

You could make this a little bit more compact by defining a `between` function:

```
between <- function(x,val1,val2) x>=val1 & x < val2
df[between(df[[my.column]],n1,n2),]
```

Comment: The question seems like [a duplicate of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462241/specifying-conditions-as-a-variable-to-subset-a-data-frame-in-r), but I hesitate to mark it so, because I like this answer better. (And looking at the "Related" column on the right, it seems this question has been asked many times.)

Comment: There are the `%<%` and `%<=%` functions in the TeachingDemos package that would allow this to be written as `df[ n1 %<=% df[[my.column]] %<% n2, ]` which saves a couple of characters compared to the `between` function.  Which is more readable is probably in the eye of the beholder.